# How to change UIDocumentInteractionController text color?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

My app has an option for a dark theme, and when that is the case, I do something like this:

```
    UILabel.appearance().textColor = .white
```

The problem is, the app provides the ability to export some text via UIDocumentInteractionController. When I do `presentPreview` it displays white text on a white background, which makes the text completely invisible. There doesn't seem to be any way to change the text color or background color of the UIDocumentInteractionController.

I tried this

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentInteractionController.self]).textColor = .black
```

but that just gives `Cannot convert value of type 'UIDocumentInteractionController.Type' to expected element type 'UIAppearanceContainer.Type'`

I've also tried setting     `UILabel.appearance().textColor = .black` before I create the UIDocumentInteractionController, but that doesn't help either - the text still appears white.

What's extra annoying, this works to change the nav bar title color:

```
let navBarTitleTextAttributes = [
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navBarTitleTextAttributes
self.dic = UIDocumentInteractionController()
...
```

But the label appearance is not responsive.

Comment: Make an instance of the document controller to return the document, which will give you access to the label guy.

Comment: @ElTomato not sure what you mean? I do have an instance (self.dic). Could you explain in an answer?